I DO NOT HAVE RANK DROP, rather good rank on Google for my Keyword, but less search impression therby traffic. Earlier it was fine. What went wrong?
I have store that was giving me good result due to good position on Google. Now I still have top position for the keyword but getting almost no traffic. On search console too there is very few impression for the keyword, though search volume for the keyword is Ok. What is happening?? I have 4-5 such keywords and it happening for all the important keyword for me. Please if any one can guide me.
I am based in India, I wanted to check my position for the Keyword in USA, so I logged on to my server which is USA and searched for the keyword, I came on top, but there was no impression for the Keyword on my google console, though the keyword has more than 300 impressions per day. I am not getting even 30 impressions in whole month. I it happening with 4-5 important keywords for me. Please Help

Did you search in a private window, otherwise you may be seeing personalised results.
